# Scraping Target Prices in Scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I am trying to code a web scraper using Scrapy that scrapes the price of a product from target, but it seems that the price is gotten via javascript. I was thinking about using selenium but I am not sure how I would do this. Do you have any suggestions on how? My code is below.

```
import scrapy


class TargetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'target'
    allowed_domains = ['target.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.target.com/p/red-blend-wine-750ml-bottle-california-roots-8482/-/A-52525405#lnk=sametab']

    def parse(self, response):
        price = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]')
        print(price)
```

Comment: your alternatives are to use selenium (or any browser emulator) or to reverse engineer that request to understand where the information you need is coming from

Answer (score 0):

There are some options to render javascript pages. If you would like to use Python you can use [Scrapy-Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) / [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) / [Playwright](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python).

If you are ok with NodeJs you can use [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) / [Playwright](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright)

I prefer Puppeteer if I need to render a page.

Here is the solution for you.

> npm i puppeteer

File name: price.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.target.com/p/red-blend-wine-750ml-bottle-california-roots-8482/-/A-52525405#lnk=sametab');
  let price = await page.evaluate(()=>{
      return document.querySelector('div[data-test="product-price"]').innerText;
  });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: There are Scrapy plugins for all mentioned technologies, not just for Splash.